# Redeemed Stripe Coupons Report (Sigma)

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to generate a report of coupons redeemed by month but am not getting correct numbers.  So I did this query to give me all time redemptions for a specific coupon:

```
select
   count(*) as Redeemed
from
  subscriptions 
where  subscriptions.discount_coupon_id = 'FREE25OFF'
```

This returns 129:

[image]

However, when I view how many redemptions it has in the Stripe control panel, it says it has been redeemed 1,209 times:

[image]

I don't understand the discrepancy here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is better to query against the Invoice table.  That solved the issue!

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. For anyone who might find it helpful, here was my final Sigma Query for who used a specific coupon:

```
select
  id as invoice_id,
  customer_id,
  amount_paid as total_user_paid,
  currency,
  transfer_data_amount as total_paid_out
from
  invoices
WHERE
  (
    date BETWEEN date('2022-06-01')
    AND date('2022-06-30')
  )
  AND discount_coupon_id = 'couponid123'
  AND paid = true
order by
  date desc;
````